# Changing gsettings for another user from an ansible script (started by vagrant)

Tags: unity, sudo, gsettings

I asked the question already on stackoverflow, but figured, that this could be a better place to get an answer: I want to provision a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16 LTS using vagrant and ansible (local). Part of the provisioning is to add and remove some Unity launcher icons for a user that is also created by the same script. The script is started from the `vagrant` user. After searching through several related questions, I tried variations of

- `dbus-launch --exit-with-session` before the gsettings command
- `become_flags: '-i'`
- `become_flags: '-H'`
- `become_flags: '-E'`

on the following basic ansible command

```
- name: Remove Launcher Icons
  command: gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'application://atom.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ user }}"
```

So far, no success, BUT running the command as a logged in user works.

**EDIT**
My best appoach for a solution would be launching a shell script from ansible instead of doing the change in ansible directly. However, I am not sure how it should look like.

Comment: If your other question is still on Stackoverflow, please delete that one. Cross-posted questions are frowned upon on SE network

Comment: OK, thank you for the hint, I will delete the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you place a `.desktop` file into each user's `~/.config/autostart` folder that will call launcher setup script. Alternatively, place `.desktop` file into `/etc/xdg/autostart` so that script runs for every user, but then you'll need to grab username and find user launcher config in some form of database. Id personally use Python script that reads json file with username: launcher list valies, because it's simple.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the script then runs, whenever a user logs in, as that user. This would also mean, that the script must handle later additions to the launcher by the user (at least not overwrite them).

Comment: @bln-tom  technically, yes. If your user adds something to launcher, normally that'd stay there. But you have a script that alters the launcher each time, so the has to be something to detect changes as well.

Comment: I plan to let the shell file also create a extra file as a marker that it has been executed. So on the second provisioning run, I let the shell file remove the .desktop file again

Comment: @bin-tom I rolled back the additions you made to my answer. I appreciate the improvement but the code you wrote isn't my original work, hence feel like it's wrong for me to take credit for it. If you wish, please post your own answer with that content. I understand and don't mind if unaccepting my post is necessary

Answer (score 4):

I've also struggled with setting the launcher favorites via ansible.

For me the solution was to use the ansible `dconf` module instead of `gsettings`:

```
- name: set icons/applications
  dconf:
    key: /com/canonical/unity/launcher/favorites
    value: "{{ launcher_favorites }}"
    state: present
```

I guess it also works with other users via `become_user` (but I haven't tested it).